# download string object content as plain text file with Mozilla Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, download

In my FF extension I create an object (a string) retrieving data from the DOM.

Now I need to download a plain text file with the string content. The result should be a CSV file.

I read about `addDownload` method but I miss a lot of pieces... any hint?

Mainly I don't know how to:

1. "transform" my string in a downloadable object (a file?)
2. correctly call the `addDownload` method (nsIURI, etc)

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: So what you really want to do is to write a string to a file?

Comment: yes, I collect some content from the DOM in a string and I need to download a text file with that content. I could store the content in another type of object if a string could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of approaches. The old-school way is to manipulate `nsIFile` and `nsIFileOutputStream` directly, although you can't write null bytes this way. You can also create an `nsIStringInputStream` from your string and write that to your output stream, or you can use `nsIAsyncStreamCopier` to copy it asynchronously. `FileUtils.jsm` and `NetUtil.jsm` exist to try to make this easier for you.

However, if you are targetting new enough versions of Firefox, you can ignore all that and use the [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File) API instead.

Comment: so I don't ever need to use `addDownload` method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDownloadManager#addDownload%28%29

Comment: No, that's not really useful for anything else other than downloading files from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of my extension, it shows the save as dialog so the user can pick the correct location (you can skip that part or try to find out where the downloads should be placed automatically)

```
const nsIFilePicker = Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker;

var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"]
.createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
fp.init(window, "Save as", nsIFilePicker.modeSave);
fp.appendFilters(nsIFilePicker.filterHTML);
fp.appendFilters(nsIFilePicker.filterAll);

var rv = fp.show();
if (rv == nsIFilePicker.returnOK || rv == nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {
var file = fp.file;

// work with returned nsILocalFile...
// Check that it has some extension
var name = file.leafName;
if (-1==name.indexOf('.'))
file.leafName = name + '.html' ;

// file is nsIFile, data is a string
var foStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
.createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);

// use 0x02 | 0x10 to open file for appending.
foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0);
// write, create, truncate

foStream.write(data, data.length);
foStream.close();
```